# Not able to insert into database. Getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-restcontroller

I am trying insert data into mysql. But whenever I call the service I get the below mentioned error.

**Project Setup:**

> Project Build : **Gradle**
>
> Backend Server : **Mysql**
>
> an hava java, resources type structure similar to maven.

***MainApplication with main method***

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Application Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {


    @Bean
    public DataDao getDao() {
        return new DataDaoImp();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
//        return new HibernateTemplate(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory());
        return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory());
//        return new HibernateTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        return new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(getDataSource())
                .addAnnotatedClasses(Users.class, LogRequest.class, Person.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/startuptest");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibTransMan(){
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
2016-07-24 15:51:18.254 ERROR 25228 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource] with root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1062) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar!/:1.4]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.savePerson(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.startupapp.controller.MainController.testInsert(MainController.java:45) ~[app-server-rest-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

**Spring Boot logs**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

2016-07-24 15:50:47.947  INFO 25228 --- [           main] com.example.startupapp.MainApplication   : Starting MainApplication on compaq with PID 25228 (/home/vishal/Projects/git/StartUpApp/server/build/libs/app-server-rest-service-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by vishal in /home/vishal/Projects/git/StartUpApp/server)
2016-07-24 15:50:47.962  INFO 25228 --- [           main] com.example.startupapp.MainApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-07-24 15:50:48.054  INFO 25228 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@29d30294: startup date [Sun Jul 24 15:50:48 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-24 15:50:50.195  INFO 25228 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4a3c13c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-24 15:50:50.964  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-07-24 15:50:50.990  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-07-24 15:50:50.993  INFO 25228 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
2016-07-24 15:50:51.181  INFO 25228 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-07-24 15:50:51.182  INFO 25228 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3133 ms
2016-07-24 15:50:51.904  INFO 25228 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-07-24 15:50:51.911  INFO 25228 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-24 15:50:51.912  INFO 25228 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-24 15:50:51.912  INFO 25228 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-24 15:50:51.912  INFO 25228 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-24 15:50:52.407  INFO 25228 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-07-24 15:50:52.420  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2016-07-24 15:50:52.532  INFO 25228 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-07-24 15:50:52.536  INFO 25228 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800, hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20, hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5, hibernate.connection.username=root, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/startup, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.connection.password=****}
2016-07-24 15:50:52.537  INFO 25228 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-07-24 15:50:52.982  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-07-24 15:50:53.044  INFO 25228 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2016-07-24 15:50:53.057  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2016-07-24 15:50:53.216  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-07-24 15:50:53.764  INFO 25228 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2016-07-24 15:50:53.764  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2016-07-24 15:50:53.777  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2016-07-24 15:50:53.778  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-07-24 15:50:53.866  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager      : Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@57fa77b8] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2016-07-24 15:50:54.213  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@29d30294: startup date [Sun Jul 24 15:50:48 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-24 15:50:54.330  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/testing]}" onto public void com.example.startupapp.controller.MainController.testInsert()
2016-07-24 15:50:54.332  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.example.startupapp.model.LoginResult com.example.startupapp.controller.MainController.login(com.example.startupapp.model.User)
2016-07-24 15:50:54.332  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test_login]}" onto public boolean com.example.startupapp.controller.MainController.login(int)
2016-07-24 15:50:54.332  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/apply_to_guide],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.example.startupapp.model.GuideRequestResult com.example.startupapp.controller.MainController.applyToGuide(com.example.startupapp.model.GuideRequest)
2016-07-24 15:50:54.332  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.startupapp.controller.MainController.testService(java.lang.String)
2016-07-24 15:50:54.333  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/register],methods=[PUT]}" onto public com.example.startupapp.model.SimpleResult com.example.startupapp.controller.MainController.register(com.example.startupapp.model.RegisterUser)
2016-07-24 15:50:54.335  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-07-24 15:50:54.336  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-07-24 15:50:54.389  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-07-24 15:50:54.390  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-07-24 15:50:54.454  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-07-24 15:50:54.892  INFO 25228 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-07-24 15:50:55.495  INFO 25228 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-07-24 15:50:55.500  INFO 25228 --- [           main] com.example.startupapp.MainApplication   : Started MainApplication in 8.006 seconds (JVM running for 8.599)
2016-07-24 15:51:18.123  INFO 25228 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-07-24 15:51:18.124  INFO 25228 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-07-24 15:51:18.144  INFO 25228 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 20 ms
```

Comment: Let me guess you have a `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Remove it. Also why use Plan hibernate, is you really need some specific features do so, but for 80% you are better of by using plain JPA which is preconfigured by Spring boot for you.

Answer (score 1):

if you use spring-boot, you don't need any Application Configuration more. You have to use just an application.properties file in resources folder. Spring-boot automatically read this file. Please edit this file like this:

```
## JDBC part
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

You have to modify you main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.startupapp") 
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainApplication().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainApplication.class)).run(args);
    }
}
```

Remove the AppConfig.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In spring boot you do not need to define configuration class.

Replace

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
```

With

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```